# An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: entity-framework, invalidoperationexception

I have met with an error(An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code  ) . my query shows below. Please give me some pointers .

```
          return (from r in mcontext.BursaryMasters
                    join s in mcontext.AcedemicYears on r.AcademicId equals s.AcademicYearID
                    where s.AcademicYearDesc == academicYear && r.LevelID == level
                    orderby order1 ascending
                    select new Result()
                    {
                        StudentID = r.StudentID,
                        Name = r.Name,
                        Distance = r.Distance,
                        AnnualIncome = r.AnnualIncome

                    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Please show more code and say what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Set a breakpoint, debug the code, and inspect the `Exception` - usually the **inner exception** gives a hint to what the real problem is.

Comment: If you need help you need to insert at least the message and all the inner exceptions. InvalidOperationException could be everything.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the problem is in your orderby command. `order1` looks like a CLR object, is it? Then it cannot be translated to SQL. You probably wanted to replace it with some attribute of `r` or `s`, e.g. `s.SomeAttribute`.